# Jquery text when start typing inside textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox

I want when I Start typing in textbox then the `Forgot` text replace it to `View` to user can view what password he typing and if password textbox is blank then it show default text as `Forgot`. If show `View` and use click `View` link then show text in textbox or `View` replace in `Hide` and if click `Hide` then textbox text become password format.I am not familiar with jquery please any wanna help us how I make it.

My code is below:

```html
 <div class="input_field">
                        <span><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                       <input type="password" class="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" maxlength="30" minlength="8" autocomplete="new-password"/><a class="hyperlink link" href="forgot.com" id="link" style="float: right; margin-right: 5px;position: absolute;top: 7px;right: 0px;" title="I forgotten my password" >Forgot?</a></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `html` code similar code below. (add another `anchor` to toggle password visibility, and add `data-l` attribute to the `anchors`s for using in `js` code):

```js
window.onload=function(){
   var links=document.querySelectorAll("[data-l]");
   var pass=document.querySelector("#password");
   pass.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
        links.forEach(function(l){
            l.style.display= !!pass.value.trim().length==(l.getAttribute("data-l")=="true")?"":"none";
         })
   });
   document.querySelector("[data-l='true']").addEventListener("click", function(){
      pass.type=pass.type=="password"?"text":"password";
      this.innerHTML = pass.type=="text" ? "Hide Password" : "Show Password";
   });
};
```

```html
<div class="input_field">
  <span>
         <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </span>
  <input type="password" class="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" maxlength="30" minlength="8" autocomplete="new-password"/>
   <a class="hyperlink link" data-l="false" href="forgot.com" id="link" style=" margin-right: 5px;position: absolute;top: 7px;right: 0px;" title="I forgotten my password" >Forgot?</a>
   <a class="hyperlink link" data-l="true" href="javascript:;" id="link" style="display:none;margin-right: 5px;position: absolute;top: 7px;right: 0px;" title="toggle password" >Show Password</a>
</div>
```

---

**New part**:
If you want to show eye icon instead of `anchor`'s text, you can use code below:

```js
window.onload=function(){
    var links=document.querySelectorAll("[data-l]");
   var pass=document.querySelector("#password");
   pass.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
        links.forEach(function(l){
             l.style.display= !!pass.value.trim().length==(l.getAttribute("data-l")=="true")?"":"none";
         })
   });
   document.querySelector("[data-l='true']").addEventListener("click", function(){
       pass.type=pass.type=="password"?"text":"password";
       this.setAttribute("data-tp", pass.type=="text" ? "hide" : "show");
   });
};
```

```css
[data-tp='hide']{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
    background-size: 100%;
}
[data-tp='show']{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="input_field">
  <span>
         <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </span>
  <input type="password" class="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" maxlength="30" minlength="8" autocomplete="new-password"/>
   <a class="hyperlink link" data-l="false" href="forgot.com" id="link" style=" margin-right: 5px;position: absolute;top: 7px;right: 0px;" title="I forgotten my password" >Forgot?</a>
   <a class="hyperlink link" data-l="true" href="javascript:;" id="link" style="display:none;margin-right: 5px;position: absolute;top: 7px;right: 0px;" title="toggle password" data-tp='show'></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why toggle link not show `Hide` when show password clicking on Toggle password ?

Comment: I've updated my answer. now clicking on it, changes the `anchor`'s text :)

Comment: I thumbs up your answer , it is possible to add eye icon instead show and Hide text in Jquery?

Comment: I've added a new part to my answer to showing how to do it; please look at it, and upvote my answer if that was useful :)

Comment: This question `is possible to add eye icon instead show and Hide text in Jquery?` was added by you in a comment and was not a part of your main question while my answer was for your original question. removing the accept mark was not pleasant but i will update my answer :). hope it can help you... (In addition, my added part in my answer was totality of what you must do; A answer in response of a comment.). **I Have updated it now.**

Comment: Thanks but, still it is url base 64. Could you tell me what is the benifit of url and base 64.? For my knowledge

Comment: `Base64` will assigns real content (data) of an image to it and will load completely with your html (if you put these `css` in your `html` content). this causes that our images will be exist when user needs them (typing in our input box). `simple urls` needs loading image from an external resource but this not. in this way the images will load immediately. (if i understand your problem correctly)

Comment: Yes,thank u for help `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52587928/popup-when-click-link-little-like-stackoverflow-inbox-in-css`

Comment: Please delte your above comment @Hassan and respond to that answer if you have

Comment: My free times is very low @Pritam Gosai, but I will read your question as soon as possible  :)

Answer (score 2):

**If I don't misunderstood your requirements** then this way you can try with `keyup` event,

```js
let link = $('#link');
let password = $('#password');
password.keyup(function() {
  if (!!this.value) {
    $('#link').text('View');
  } else {
    $('#link').text('Forgot?');
  }

  link.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.text === "View") {
      $("#password").attr('type', 'text');
      $('#link').text('Hide');
    } else {
      $("#password").attr('type', 'password');
      $('#link').text('View');
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_field">
  <span><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  <input type="password" class="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" maxlength="30" minlength="8" autocomplete="new-password" /><a class="hyperlink link" href="forgot.com" id="link" style="float: right; margin-right: 5px;position: absolute;top: 7px;right: 0px;"
    title="I forgotten my password">Forgot?</a></div>
```

Comment: thanks but still there is issue that is (1) When I click `view` button then password not show in texts and `view` not replace into `hide`.

Comment: @PritamGosai then could you plz edit your question again with full requirements because I didn't find anywhere on your question about `hide`

Comment: @PritamGosai I've **Edited** my answer for your. Have a look again

Comment: @PritamGosai Let me know it is working or not as per your requirements?

Comment: @PritamGosai ha ha. I'm a gentle guy bro as per I know myself..it's just a name from bollywood movie dialogue :). Let me try my best I can answer your new question or not