# popup when click link little like stackoverflow inbox in css

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I want create a model page which work same like stackoverflow inbox popup. Like in image given below , when we hit the inbox icon looks small box where inside it small loader shows for messages/comments. right? >> After it expand depend on text/tables/messages.

[image]

[image]

How I add ajax jquery to load any page inside div where the `name` and `id` of div=`"pageaload"` and for example the url for load is `google.com`

> speculation request please the page for live mistake see, because my english is bad and might I not able to explain my question and causes it I get thumbs down and bad reputation my profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your post, you can try something like this:

```js
$(function(){
  var prv=$([]);
  $(".top-bar>.m-link").click(function(){
     var dst=$(this).children();
     if(dst.html("<div style='width: 50px; height: 10px'>Loading...</div>").toggle().click(function(ev){ev.stopPropagation();}).is(":visible")){
       dst.load("https://api.github.com");
      }
      if(prv[0]!=dst[0]) prv.hide();
      prv=dst;
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.top-bar{
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height: 22px;
  background-color: #444;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.top-bar>.m-link{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float:right;
  width:20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin-left:1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#pageaload{
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 420px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: solid 1px #999;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: none;
  border-top-style: none;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 4px;
  font-size: 9.5pt;
  cursor: default;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='top-bar'>
  <div class='m-link' style='background-image: url(https://png.icons8.com/ios/50/000000/plus-2-math.png)'>
    <div id='pageaload'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='m-link' style='background-image: url(https://png.icons8.com/ios/50/000000/new-message.png)'>
    <div id='pageaload' style='background-color: #a7a7a7'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, you can add a `loader png` or what you want instead of my `loading...` text. this is a project itself but i tried implement it in a full and simple example. all things depends on your own css and needs.

**TIP**:

if your destination address (which shoud be loaded in target element) has another `url` or `protocol`, you may get some security errors because `Cross Origin` problems. the address that i selected (`https://www.api.github.com`), has `Allow-Access-*` permission in server side and because this, i can use it. if your dest address for loading exists on current url address, or both of them have `http` protocol (your site and target site both), or the taget site allow you to access it (by mentioned permission), all thing will work correctly.

Hope helps you :)

Comment: `http://api.github.com` is just a sample of web actions that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` permission of it has been set up to `*` (*: all) in server side and allows you to access it without any security problem. based on my **TIP** part, if dest url is part of current web site, you can use it without any problem.

Comment: please update the answer last: what happens when I don't want to redirect url in Jquery and instead i want show `<div>` as `id="mypage"` . Where hide and show function will work. SPlease reply and help me last.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you some guidelines.

You have to learn Bootstrap to build beautiful HTML.
https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/deyGZ

In order to make life to your HTML, use [Jquery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    // This will be your starting point.

   // for your question
   // <div id='pageaload'></div>
     $.get("https://stackoverflow.com").done(function(data, status){
        $('#pageaload').html(data);
    });

});
```

Replace the url with your page to access. The stackoverflow is in different domain which will be blocked due to CORS policy.

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://stackoverflow.com/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

More detail: [Why does my JavaScript get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

Comment: Yes, the code is correct but url "https://stackoverflow" cannot be accessed directly thorugh an ajax call due to security reasons. You can replace the url with your page, that will work

Comment: Check the browser console that will show you the warning message. Hope this helps